# Displaying Database Values in Date Groups

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, html-table

I have a MySQL database with a table called NAMES as follows:

```
========   ==========   ===========
date       name1        name2
========   ==========   ===========
01/01/15   nameA        nameB
01/01/15   nameC        nameD
02/01/15   nameE        nameF
03/01/15   nameG        nameH
03/01/15   nameI        nameJ
03/01/15   nameK        nameL
04/01/15   nameM        nameN
```

I want to output the values into a table as follows:

```
==============================================
                   01/01/15
==============================================
          nameA              nameB
          nameC              nameD
==============================================
                   02/01/15
==============================================
          nameE              nameF
==============================================
                   03/01/15
==============================================
          nameG              nameH
          nameI              nameJ
          nameK              nameL
==============================================
                   04/01/15
==============================================
          nameM              nameN
```

Am I looking for a FOREACH loop?

This is the code I'm working with at the moment ...

```php
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY date ASC") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
    echo '<table>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name1'].'</td><td>'.$row['name2'].'</td></tr>;
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Yes you are. Test the date if it's the same dont print your header row if its different do

Comment: Typically a `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` loop is used.

Comment: I have the while loop, just struggling with breaking up each group of values by the date. Just trying Mike Miller's suggestion now, seems simple enough.

Comment: You can use aliases for this with  `GROUP BY`

Comment: I've included the PHP code I'm working with at the moment, can someone tweak it with a working foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Test date in each loop. If its empty or has changed since previous loop do you header row.

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY date ASC") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());  
$date=null;
echo '<table>';     
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))   {       
    If($date !==$row['date']){
        $date=$row['date'];
        //and echo your header html
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name1'].'</td><td>'.$row['name2'].'</td></tr>; 
 }
 echo '</table>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in another post, here's the code for anyone with a similar query:

```html
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY date ASC") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
 $date = "";
 echo '<table>';
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
   if ($date !== $row["date"]) {
      $date = $row["date"];
   echo "<tr><td>$date</td></tr>";
     {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name1'].'</td><td>'.$row['name2'].'</td></tr>;
        }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: That's the one! You might want to use the span attribute on the date field like this `span="2" ` so the cell spans whole table width

Comment: Most definitely Mike Miller, I'm literally just adding that now - thank you very much for you help.

Comment: No problemos! Classic problem